# PostgreSQL Native Replication | Master - Master

Tags: debian, postgresql, cluster, replication, failover

I am configuring a high availability environment with Debian 9.4 machine, in which I have a [Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) working and need to include [native PostgreSQL 9.6 replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/high-availability.html), but by default this method of replication is unidirectional, ie it is just a streaming from the database from the Master cluster to the Slave, without it being able to edit the database.

I would like to know if there is any software or some specific configuration that allows me to perform this replication in a bidirectional way using the native PostgreSQL replication, where the two clusters are taken as Master, I did several searches and found solutions like [Pgpool](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page), but this type of solution does not serve me because of the need for a unique machine for process management.